# Zend Framework - Accessing custom configuration files

Tags: php, zend-framework

I created a custom XML configuration file called config.xml and placed it in the configs directory in the Zend Framework. I want to use it in one of my controllers using Zend_Config_Xml. What I have is not working, and it says "An error occurred. Application error". How do I read in a custom XML config file from a controller? This is what I have in my controller so far:

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        // action body
        $config = new Zend_Config_Xml('config.xml', 'staging');
        echo $config->host;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail, perhaps the xml file in question.  Also have you tried doing a `var_dump($config)` to verify that the file is reading.  This scenario is very possible.

Comment: You are providing a file name without a path, are you sure it's going to be found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably just the path you need to fix:

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH.'/configs/config.xml', 'staging');
```

if not, check the error log to see what the actual error message is.

Edit: To do this in the bootstrap, the easiest (although perhaps not best) way is to add a new resource method and store the config object in the registry. Add this to your bootstrap class:

```
protected function _initCustomConfig()
{
    $config = new Zend_Config_Xml('config.xml', 'staging');
    Zend_Registry::set('config', $config);

    return $config;
}
```

you can then access it later using:

```
$config = Zend_Registry::get('config');
```

Comment: I've edited my answer to show you how to do this in the bootstrap instead.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Just curious, does the Bootstrap class get instantiated on every request, firing all methods that start with _init? Also,do you know if the Zend_Registry gets reset on every request or does it store it in some kind of persistent storage location? The documentation says it is always available throughout your application. My guess that this is just a global class with static entries.

Comment: Yes, the bootstrap and its init methods are run on every request. Zend_Registry does not persistent between requests, it is just a global class with static entries as you suspected.

Answer (score 1):

If you're debugging the issue locally, first enable better error reporting by adding these commands in your application.ini's development section:

```
phpSettings.error_reporting         = E_ALL
phpSettings.display_startup_errors  = 1
phpSettings.display_errors          = 1
```

By default, zend framework doesn't show internal errors.

If you're loading a `Zend_Config` file, it's always better to load it using an absolute path.

```
public function indexAction()
    {
        // action body
        $config = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/config.xml', 'staging');
        echo $config->host;
    }
```